# Pass params through switch navigator react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to pass params through a switch navigator but it's not currently working. I have two separate stack navigators and a switch navigator to navigate between the two. The first is a login/verification page and the other is just the main homescreen.

I got the params to pass through the first stack navigator (for logging in and verifying) but can't get that data to the second stack navigator.

Verification.js -- here is where I navigate to the main homescreen and where i want to pass the params through

```
    signin = async() => {
    const {state} = this.props.navigation;
    const { Name, Address, Phone, NPI } = state.params.item;

    await AsyncStorage.setItem("userToken", "user");

    this.props.navigation.navigate("App", {item: {
        Name: Name,
        Address: Address,
        Phone: Phone,
        NPI: NPI,
    }
    })
}
```

Homescreen.js -- here is where I want to receive those params however right now NPI is undefined and are no params

```
 writeUserData() {
        const {state} = this.props.navigation.state;
        const  NPI = state.params.item.NPI;

        const key = firebase.database().ref("/perscriptions").push().key;

        firebase.database().ref("/").child(key).set({
           surname: this.state.patientSurName,
           zip_code: this.state.zip_code,
           Sex: this.state.patientSex,
           DOB: this.state.patientDOB,
           Name: this.state.patientName,
           NPI: NPI

        })
        Alert.alert("Perscription Submitted!")


        this.reset_data()

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anyone wants to know the answer too, there are two options you have:

1. You can use react-redux by creating a store and then updating the store with your information. (probably the best way to do it).
2. You can use the async storage built into react-native (definitely easier but not the best method)